# How to send all csv data to database table in magento2?

Tags: magento2, php

I have to send all csv data which have two column and multiple records, but it send of first row data for save. i have to submit request path and target path to table via csv. i am using this code in one file in root and hit directly.

please see my code :

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
         $params = $_SERVER;
            $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
            $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

            $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
            $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("url_data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
             $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    $urlRewrite = $objectManager->create(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite::class);

    $urlRewrite->load(0);

    $model = $urlRewrite;
    $data['entity_type']      = 'custom';
    $data['request_path']     = $data[0];
    $data['target_path']      = $data[1];
    $data['redirect_type']    = 301;
    $data['store_id']         = 1;

   $objectManager->get(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite::class)->validateRequestPath($data['request_path']);
    $model->setEntityType($data['entity_type'])
        ->setRequestPath($data['request_path'])
        ->setTargetPath($data['target_path'])
        ->setRedirectType($data['redirect_type'])
        ->setStoreId($data['store_id'])
        ->setDescription("Imported Urls");

    $model->save();
     }
 }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

anyone have any idea for that, what i am missing please.